# Three.js PointLights not working correctly with Lambert material

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to create a scene lit by PointLights but the lights are not working as expected when using Lambert material. It looks like the lights only render when both lights reach the surface.

When I tried to use Phong material, it renders correctly.

My renderer:

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMap.renderSingleSided = false;
```

Plane:

```
var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(40, 40, 1, 1);
var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial();
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry,planeMaterial);
plane.receiveShadow = true;
```

Walls:

```
var boxMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0x457dd8 });
var boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(9, 2, 0.2, 1, 1, 1);
var box = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry, boxMaterial);
box.castShadow = true;
box.receiveShadow = true;
```

Ambient light

```
var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight("#999292");
```

and pointLights:

```
var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xff0000, 20, 50);
pointLight.position.set(16, 1.5, 15.5);
pointLight.castShadow = true;
```

What am I doing wrong? I think it may be a bug.

Here is my example: https://jsfiddle.net/aojnmspn/

I am using Three.js R87